# MS Outlook 2010 Warning

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Pretty sure this isn't the right stack exchange for this, but I'm giving it a shot anyway:

I keep getting the following dialog box from Outlook:

[image: dialog box from Outlook]

My antivirus software is up to date, I have tried every setting I can find, and still this annoying thing is in my face all day.  I have tried to track down the program that is requesting access (like bluetooth PIM access, for instance), but I'm at a loss short of killing one process at a time.

Does anyone have any ideas for tracking down the offending program, or can you at least point me to the right Stack Exchange site?

As always, any and all help* will be appreciated.

*This is a corporate environment, so I can't just change email clients.

Answer (score 2):

I would try downloading and running Process Monitor ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 ) which is a great tool to see what each program is accessing in real time (network, files, registry keys, etc). I personally use this all the time when debugging unfamiliar programs that do not follow traditional best practices when storing files in weird or unfamiliar directories. You will be able to spot trends or interactions. I normally export logs to CSV and import them into excel to find patterns using tables and pivot tables. You actually can use the program itself to perform the filtering but I actually like using tables inside of excel 2007 and 2010. Try downloading it and upload the logs to an ftp if you cannot figure out the interaction.

I have seen this error twice. Once when Acess was accessing outlook and another time with a screen capture program, snagit, was told to send an image to an email recipient.

Information about how to disable Outlook Security pop-ups. : google "Avoid A program is trying to access e-mail address information" . Then look for add-in-express domain and outlook-security-manager-addins article.